# Mercurial: Is there a way to make a diff compared to local repository, not remote?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, diff, patch

I've comitted several changes in my mercurial repository. And now I want to see the difference between my local copy and the original remote repository. So it would be same if I collected diffs of all my commits by hand, but they're too split up.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: What do you mean by "they're too split up"?

Comment: Doesn't `hg diff -r X:` do what you want, where X is the revision you cloned/pulled to last?

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
hg outgoing --patch
```

If you want more details or information :

```
hg outgoing --help
```